# error parsing json data (value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to json array)

Tags: php, android, json

i am trying to implement simple android application where i am trying to retrieve the database values over php site, but the following code generates error parsing json data.

my php file encoding json is as below

```
getdeals.php
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="user"; // Database name
$tbl_name="deal"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host","$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deal");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

table deal is as below
[image: table deal]

android class is as below

```
public class JsonConnect extends Activity {

    InputStream is;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json_connect);
        addListenerOnbutton();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                getDeals();
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_json_connect, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void addListenerOnbutton() {

        final Context context = this;

        Button home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();  

            }

        });
 }

    public void getDeals() {

        String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        //ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/dealnow/getdeals.php");
                //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","dealid: "+json_data.getString("deal_id")+
                                ", hotel name: "+json_data.getString("hotel_name")+
                                ", valid date: "+json_data.getInt("valid_date")+
                                ", location: "+json_data.getString("location")+
                                ", website: "+json_data.getString("website")
                        );
                }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and finally logcat output is

```
05-11 01:23:08.767: D/dalvikvm(435): GC_EXPLICIT freed 24K, 4% free 6582K/6855K, paused 7ms+4ms

05-11 01:29:24.164: V/TLINE(497): new: android.text.TextLine@4065aa30

05-11 01:29:24.757: D/dalvikvm(497): GC_CONCURRENT freed 115K, 4% free 6560K/6791K, paused 5ms+14ms

05-11 01:29:24.764: E/log_tag(497): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

05-11 01:29:24.844: V/TLINE(497): new: android.text.TextLine@4065d8e0

05-11 01:34:12.147: D/dalvikvm(497): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 4% free 6524K/6791K, paused 7ms+3ms
```

how can i get the desired values of the table

please help.

Comment: can you post the JSON Reponse?

Comment: @VishalPawale : can you tell me where to get it?

Comment: By JSON response, I mean the response returned by server/php script.
In your case its `result` variable.

Comment: @VishalPawale : when i run getdeals.php it generates the error:Undefined variable: output in C:\wamp\www\dealnow\getdeals.php on line 16

Comment: So there is error in your php script, thats why android app is not able to parse the response.

Comment: @VishalPawale : can you tell me what actually i should change in my getdeals.php which is given above

Comment: You need to put `$output=array();` somewhere before the while loop.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn after declaring that the it does not generates error but only prints `[]`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn : it did the trick, my table was empty before... after i inserted values it worked

Comment: @VishalPawale You should put your comment as the answer so OP can close the question. You did the work.

Comment: Put the comment as Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response returned by PHP script is not in valid JSON format.

You need to put `$output=array();` somewhere before the while loop